# To extract the data between two Strings(time intervals) from a log file or text document using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, text-files, logfile

I have a log file which is in MB and I need to extract the data only for one particular hour and exclude the remaining data.

I tried achieving it by copying every line in the log file using time stamp and I'm able to extract data using that but when an exception is recorded in the log file I'm not able to capture it as it is not having time stamp in all the lines. I need that as well.

```
Do Until FileIn.AtEndOfStream
    strTmp = FileIn.ReadLine
    If Len(strTmp) > 0 Then
        If (InStr(1, strTmp, Date & " " & LastHour, vbTextCompare) > 0) Then
            Fileout.WriteLine strTmp
        End If
    End If
Loop
```

Code for extracting data line by line which is having timestamp

I need to take the 1 hr data from log file save it in a text document.

Can someone help me with this please?

**sample log file**

> ```
> 2019-01-02 00:54:08,886 [117] ERROR [(null)] - 
> ************START***************** Application Exception 2019-01-02 12:54:08 AM*****************************   
>
>
> ERROR CODE             :::::: acdefba1-fdfc-4cef-bah5-082bjdbdd9e
>
> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>    at DynamicModule.ns.Wrapped_IDeliveryModelService_bc245ed8140c4a49aeaf2e2b7c9c7578.UpdateCart(FXCContextctx)  
>
> *************END******************* Application Exception 2019-01-02 12:54:08 AM*************************  
>
> 2019-01-02 00:54:08,965 [95] DEBUG...  2019-01-02 01:01:08,965 [95] DEBUG...  2019-01-02 01:01:08,965 [95] DEBUG...
> ```

```
Sub ExtractLogs(textfilename, logfilename)
    'Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2
    Dim fso, FileIn, Fileout, strTmp, count, Data


    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set FileIn = fso.OpenTextFile(logfilename, 1)
    Set Fileout = fso.CreateTextFile(file_path & textfilename, 2, True)

     If Len(Hour(Time)) = 1 Then
               Lasthour = "0" & Hour(Time) - 1
               If (Len(Lasthour) > 2) Then Lasthour = "23"
               Currenthour = "0" & Hour(Time)
            Else
               Lasthour = Hour(Time) - 1
               Currenthour = Hour(Time)
            End If

    count = 0
    Data = ""
    Do Until FileIn.AtEndOfStream
       strTmp = FileIn.ReadLine
       If Len(strTmp) > 0 Then
            If (InStr(1, strTmp, Date & " " & Lasthour, vbTextCompare) > 0) Then
                'Fileout.writeLine
                Fileout.writeLine Data & strTmp
                count = 1
                Data = ""
            ElseIf (InStr(1, strTmp, Date & " " & Currenthour, vbTextCompare) > 0) Then
                count = 2
            End If

            If (InStr(1, strTmp, Date & " " & Lasthour, vbTextCompare) < 1 And count = 1) Then
                Data = Data & vbNewLine & strTmp
                End If
        End If
    Loop

    FileIn.Close
    Fileout.Close
```

I have modified the code like this and I'm able to extract all the data between the two time stamps but the file size is getting doubled then the original one. what should I do?

Comment: It would be hard to help without knowing the layout of the data in the file.  Maybe provide an example of the data specifically with the exception.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i have added a part of the log file which contains logs for every hour, if you can see line 4 and 6 doesn't start with a timestamp, i want them also to be part of the extracted text file.

Comment: Could you put full log file to some cloud storage? Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Let's assume that the input log file is ordered by time. Then you can find the starting position from where to read using a [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm). You can end looping of the lines when you reach a timestamp that is later than the end of your time window.

For implementing the binary search you will have to open the file in binary mode *(open for binary access read*). If all records are of equal length you can read the timestamp easily with *get*. Otherwise just read a sufficiently long string with *get* and split it at *vbcrlf* to get a single record.